# checkWakeLocks caught Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, sleep, runtime-error, wakelock

I have an app that calls a class from the receiver below. It works fine when the phone is awake, but as soon as it is put to sleep, it returns the following error from logcat: E/DeepSleepService(745): checkWakeLocks caught Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/power/active_wake_lock: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I am testing on Android 4.0.4; DROID RAZR Build/6.7.2-180_DHD-16_M4-31

Here is the the receiver class:

```
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Tried this alone, which is supposed to handle the wakelock:
        //AlarmAlertWakeLock.acquireCpuWakeLock(context);

        //Also tried manually acquiring and releasing:
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "wakelock");
        wl.acquire();
        //Results were the same for either code

        context.startService(new Intent(context, Track.class));

        wl.release();

    }

}
```

Here is the AlarmAlertWakeLock class:

```
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    class AlarmAlertWakeLock {
        private static PowerManager.WakeLock sCpuWakeLock;

        static void acquireCpuWakeLock(Context context) {
            if (sCpuWakeLock != null) {
                return;
            }
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

            sCpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "AlarmAlertWakeLock");
            sCpuWakeLock.acquire();
        }

        static void releaseCpuLock() {
            if (sCpuWakeLock != null) {
                sCpuWakeLock.release();
                sCpuWakeLock = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have registered the receiver and added permission in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<receiver android:name="com.myApp.OnAlarmReceiver" 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="OnAlarmReceiver">
</receiver>
```

Logcat:

```
11-09 18:29:09.718: E/LSApp_App(21784): Sending Message to Handler (com.motorola.contextual.virtualsensor.locationsensor.LocationDetection$MessageHandler) {4142d448}: msg :1010003
11-09 18:29:09.797: E/RulePersistence(21784): getActiveRulesString(): move to first failed
11-09 18:29:10.742: E/ConditionBuilderService(21784): vSensorCreation string is null
11-09 18:29:10.765: E/ConditionBuilderService(21784): Condition sensor table cursor closed
11-09 18:29:10.836: E/ConditionBuilderService(21784): Condition sensor table cursor closed
11-09 18:29:11.031: E/ConditionBuilderService(21784): Condition sensor table cursor closed
11-09 18:29:20.320: E/ExternalAccountType(759): Unsupported attribute readOnly
11-09 18:29:21.812: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Activity onCreate() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Activity onCreate() start
11-09 18:29:21.890: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Activity onCreate() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Activity onCreate() end
11-09 18:29:25.883: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Activity initSpyService() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Activity initSpyService() start
11-09 18:29:25.890: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Activity initSpyService() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Activity initSpyService() end
11-09 18:29:52.906: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: DoInBackground-inputs(21961): mm@mm.com-qqaazzxx
11-09 18:29:52.906: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: authenticateInfo() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: authenticateInfo() start
11-09 18:29:54.601: E/response:(21961): {"d":"userPassMatch"}
11-09 18:29:54.601: E/response:(21961): disconnected
11-09 18:29:54.601: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: DoInBackground-result(21961): userPassMatch
11-09 18:29:54.664: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() start
11-09 18:29:54.664: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() with the auto-boot load intent(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() with the auto-boot load intent
11-09 18:29:54.672: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() start
11-09 18:29:54.703: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() end
11-09 18:29:54.703: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() eulaTest passed, continue..(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() eulaTest passed, continue..
11-09 18:29:54.703: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive() end
11-09 18:29:54.789: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged NETWORKlistener(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged NETWORKlistener
11-09 18:29:54.789: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() NETWORK locationChanged still listening... accuracy: 3948.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() NETWORK locationChanged still listening... accuracy: 3948.0
11-09 18:29:56.750: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Acquiring cpu wake lock(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Acquiring cpu wake lock
11-09 18:29:56.750: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: sCpuWakeLock is null(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: sCpuWakeLock is null
11-09 18:29:56.804: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: onStartCommand() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: onStartCommand() start
11-09 18:29:56.804: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLatestTimestampValues() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLatestTimestampValues() start
11-09 18:29:56.804: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() gps 401(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() gps 401
11-09 18:29:56.804: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation: 3948.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation: 3948.0
11-09 18:29:56.804: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation lat: 39.2077425(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation lat: 39.2077425
11-09 18:29:56.804: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation long: -77.7477822(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation long: -77.7477822
11-09 18:29:56.804: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() 1.2(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() 1.2
11-09 18:29:56.812: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: GetLatestTimestamp(21961): Before
11-09 18:29:57.187: E/response:(21961): {"d":"1352320124198|1352043411304|1352481165115|1352477440841"}
11-09 18:29:57.187: E/response:(21961): disconnected
11-09 18:29:57.187: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: GetLatestTimestamp(21961): after
11-09 18:29:57.195: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: result length: 1(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: result length: 1
11-09 18:29:57.195: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData() start
11-09 18:29:57.195: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): getting the call_log/calls URI(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): getting the call_log/calls URI
11-09 18:29:57.195: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): query the calls cursor(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): query the calls cursor
11-09 18:29:57.195: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): query the calls cursor(21961): [ 11-09 18:29:57.195 21961:0x55c9 E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getPhoneData() exception - Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getPhoneData() exception - Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{414967a8 21961:com.spyphone1/10006} (pid=21961, uid=10006) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
11-09 18:29:57.195: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: 6 routine end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: 6 routine end
11-09 18:29:57.195: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllSMSData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllSMSData() start
11-09 18:29:57.203: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getWebBrowserHistoryData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getWebBrowserHistoryData() start
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getWebBrowserHistoryData() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getWebBrowserHistoryData() end
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() start
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 400(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 400
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 401(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 401
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() gps 401(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() gps 401
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation: 3948.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation: 3948.0
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation lat: 39.2077425(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation lat: 39.2077425
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation long: -77.7477822(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation long: -77.7477822
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() 1.2(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() 1.2
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 4(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 4
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() currentLatitude: 39.2077425(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() currentLatitude: 39.2077425
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() currentLongitude: -77.7477822(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() currentLongitude: -77.7477822
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() time: 1352503794731(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() time: 1352503794731
11-09 18:29:57.258: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() start
11-09 18:29:57.265: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() end
11-09 18:29:57.265: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() end
11-09 18:29:57.265: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: processTrackingData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: processTrackingData() start
11-09 18:29:57.273: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: GetLatestTimestamp(21961): Before
11-09 18:29:57.375: E/response:(21961): {"d":"{success}"}
11-09 18:29:57.375: E/response:(21961): disconnected
11-09 18:29:57.375: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: GetLatestTimestamp(21961): after
11-09 18:29:57.375: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLatestTimestampValues() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLatestTimestampValues() end
11-09 18:29:57.375: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: onStartCommand() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: onStartCommand() end
11-09 18:29:57.383: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged NETWORKlistener(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged NETWORKlistener
11-09 18:29:57.383: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() NETWORK locationChanged still listening... accuracy: 3948.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() NETWORK locationChanged still listening... accuracy: 3948.0
11-09 18:29:57.781: E/libgps(375): recv_command_status() : fix returned error code 9
11-09 18:29:57.781: E/libgps(375): numsats histogram: 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
11-09 18:29:57.781: E/libgps(375): sats histogram: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
11-09 18:29:59.461: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged listener(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged listener
11-09 18:29:59.461: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged listener(21961): [ 11-09 18:29:59.468 21961:0x55c9 E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged done. within 20 meters of current working fix. acSPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged done. within 20 meters of current working fix. accuracy - 16.0
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Acquiring cpu wake lock(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: Acquiring cpu wake lock
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: sCpuWakeLock != null(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: sCpuWakeLock != null
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: onStartCommand() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: onStartCommand() start
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLatestTimestampValues() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLatestTimestampValues() start
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() gps 401(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() gps 401
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation: 16.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation: 16.0
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation lat: 39.14668123333333(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation lat: 39.14668123333333
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation long: -77.7596563(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation long: -77.7596563
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation: 3948.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation: 3948.0
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation lat: 39.2077425(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation lat: 39.2077425
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation long: -77.7477822(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation long: -77.7477822
11-09 18:30:56.726: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() 1(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() 1
11-09 18:30:56.734: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: GetLatestTimestamp(21961): Before
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/response:(21961): {"d":"1352320124198|1352043411304|1352503794731|1352477440841"}
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/response:(21961): disconnected
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: GetLatestTimestamp(21961): after
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: result length: 1(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: result length: 1
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData() start
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): getting the call_log/calls URI(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): getting the call_log/calls URI
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): query the calls cursor(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): query the calls cursor
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllPhoneData(): query the calls cursor(21961): [ 11-09 18:30:57.343 21961:0x55c9 E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getPhoneData() exception - Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getPhoneData() exception - Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{414967a8 21961:com.spyphone1/10006} (pid=21961, uid=10006) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: 6 routine end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: 6 routine end
11-09 18:30:57.343: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllSMSData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getAllSMSData() start
11-09 18:30:57.351: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getWebBrowserHistoryData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getWebBrowserHistoryData() start
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getWebBrowserHistoryData() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getWebBrowserHistoryData() end
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() start
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 400(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 400
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 401(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 401
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() gps 401(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() gps 401
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation: 16.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation: 16.0
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation lat: 39.14668123333333(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation lat: 39.14668123333333
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation long: -77.7596563(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() curLocation long: -77.7596563
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation: 3948.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation: 3948.0
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation lat: 39.2077425(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation lat: 39.2077425
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation long: -77.7477822(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() NETWORK curLocation long: -77.7477822
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() 1(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLastKnownLocation() 1
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 4(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: gps 4
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() currentLatitude: 39.14668123333333(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() currentLatitude: 39.14668123333333
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() currentLongitude: -77.7596563(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() currentLongitude: -77.7596563
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() time: 1352503783000(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() time: 1352503783000
11-09 18:30:57.398: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() start
11-09 18:30:57.406: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() end
11-09 18:30:57.406: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getGPSData() end
11-09 18:30:57.406: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: processTrackingData() start(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: processTrackingData() start
11-09 18:30:57.414: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: GetLatestTimestamp(21961): Before
11-09 18:30:57.562: E/response:(21961): {"d":"{success}"}
11-09 18:30:57.562: E/response:(21961): disconnected
11-09 18:30:57.562: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: GetLatestTimestamp(21961): after
11-09 18:30:57.562: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLatestTimestampValues() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: getLatestTimestampValues() end
11-09 18:30:57.562: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: onStartCommand() end(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: onStartCommand() end
11-09 18:30:57.570: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged NETWORKlistener(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged NETWORKlistener
11-09 18:30:57.570: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() NETWORK locationChanged still listening... accuracy: 3948.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() NETWORK locationChanged still listening... accuracy: 3948.0
11-09 18:31:02.453: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged listener(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged listener
11-09 18:31:02.453: E/SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged still listening... accuracy: 48.0(21961): SPYPHONE_DEBUG: initGPS() locationChanged still listening... accuracy: 48.0
11-09 18:31:07.023: E/BluetoothService.cpp(375): setBluetoothTetheringNative false
11-09 18:31:07.031: E/BluetoothService(375): FTP is not supported
11-09 18:31:07.031: E/BluetoothService(375): DUN is not supported
11-09 18:31:07.031: E/BluetoothService(375): SAP is not supported
11-09 18:31:07.578: E/DeepSleepService(745): checkWakeLocks caught Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/power/active_wake_lock: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-09 18:31:07.593: E/RDS(375): RdsReadSvrMsg: READ HEADER FAIL 0 32 0
11-09 18:31:07.601: E/DeepSleepService(745): checkWakeLocks caught Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/power/active_wake_lock: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-09 18:31:07.601: E/power(375): Failed setting last user activity: g_error=0
11-09 18:31:08.211: E/AudioHardwareMot(165): Error:Unsupported key = screen_state=off
11-09 18:31:08.554: E/SecondaryTablController(159): ip route del failed: /system/bin/ip route del fe80::1:2:3:4/128 via :: dev rmnet0 table 60
11-09 18:31:08.554: E/ConnectivityService(375): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove rmnet0 secondary fe80::1:2:3:4 128 ::} failed with code 400 : {ip route modification failed (No such device)}
11-09 18:31:08.586: E/SecondaryTablController(159): ip route del failed: /system/bin/ip route del ::/0 via fe80::1:2:3:4 dev rmnet0 table 60
11-09 18:31:08.593: E/ConnectivityService(375): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove rmnet0 secondary :: 0 fe80::1:2:3:4} failed with code 400 : {ip route modification failed (No such device)}
11-09 18:31:08.601: E/ConnectivityService(375): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove rmnet0 default 2001:4888:2:fffe:a0:d:0:3 128 fe80::1:2:3:4} failed with code 400 : {Failed to remove route from default table (No such device)}
11-09 18:31:08.609: E/ConnectivityService(375): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove rmnet0 default 2001:4888:3:fffe:c0:d:0:3 128 fe80::1:2:3:4} failed with code 400 : {Failed to remove route from default table (No such device)}
11-09 18:31:08.656: E/IMSCNative(785): There is no UnRegistration success or fail received before operation completed.
11-09 18:31:08.679: E/ConnectivityService(375): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove rmnet1 default 10.168.113.229 32 0.0.0.0} failed with code 400 : {Failed to remove route from default table (No such device)}
11-09 18:31:08.687: E/ConnectivityService(375): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove rmnet1 default 0.0.0.0 0 10.168.113.229} failed with code 400 : {Failed to remove route from default table (No such device)}
11-09 18:31:08.734: E/ConnectivityService(375): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove rmnet1 default fe80::2:2:3:4 128 ::} failed with code 400 : {Failed to remove route from default table (No such device)}
11-09 18:31:08.734: E/ConnectivityService(375): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove rmnet1 default :: 0 fe80::2:2:3:4} failed with code 400 : {Failed to remove route from default table (No such device)}
11-09 18:31:09.218: E/IMSService(669): on handleMessage with 2 event
11-09 18:31:11.656: E/Tethering(375): Can't get networkInfo
11-09 18:31:11.679: E/Tethering(375): Can't get networkInfo
11-09 18:31:11.804: E/Tethering(375): Can't get networkInfo
11-09 18:31:12.211: E/PolicyLoader(22161): Couldn't find or open policies file moto_policies.xml
11-09 18:31:12.531: E/C2DMRegistrar(842): [C2DMReg] handleRequest caught org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://android.clients.google.com refused
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686): Error parsing packet: 
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686): java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tag </stream:stream> to close start tag <stream:stream> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</query></iq><iq type="result" id="vb43G-85"/>... @1:519
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686):    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3044)
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686):    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3055)
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686):    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1153)
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686):    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1102)
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parseXMPPPacket(PacketReader.java:503)
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:338)
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:62)
11-09 18:31:12.961: E/PacketReader(686):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:99)
11-09 18:31:13.336: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311):  intent false android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE mMotoConnectActivated - false
11-09 18:31:13.343: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311): N/W connectivity = false
11-09 18:31:13.398: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311): Service Connected
11-09 18:31:13.453: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311): MCSvc isUserSetup, isAuthenticated, ready ->false false true
11-09 18:31:13.453: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311): Not Activated
11-09 18:31:13.664: E/IMSCNetwork(785): isImsModeValid, IMSCConfReader is not started
11-09 18:31:14.672: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311):  intent false android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE mMotoConnectActivated - false
11-09 18:31:14.672: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311): N/W connectivity = false
11-09 18:31:15.797: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311):  intent false android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE mMotoConnectActivated - false
11-09 18:31:15.797: E/MCDashboardWidgetProvider(22311): N/W connectivity = true
```

Any idea what is causing this error when the phone is put to sleep, and how to fix?

Comment: Post all of your LogCat errors, so we can see what is happening. Also please use the "block code format" (Ctrl+K) to format your LogCat in your question.

Comment: StackOverflow thinks I am this person, but I never posted this. Weird.